# ComboBox List Add Items From Database During User Input

Tags: c#, database, filter, combobox, db2

### Explanation

> Typing in Combobox adds items from the database that `contain%` the given string. It is too much data, so I'm having to `limit` the query else the program freezes. The limit prevents future updates to my Combobox, and any attempt to clear the items per text changed event causes a crash with the error: *Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt*. In addition to the crash, I need the `limit` removed, but doing so causes the items added to flood the Combobox with too much data, e.g. the 10,000+ items.

### Text Update Event

```
private void PartDescription_TextUpdate()
        {
            OdbcLink.ConnectODBC(this, $"Select DISTINCT PM_PRT, PM_DES, PM_NET " +
                $"From PFWF0022.PARTMAST WHERE PM_PRT LIKE '{partNumberInput.Text}%' LIMIT 10");
        }
```

*Yes, I realize this query is susceptible to SQL injection but I need to work out the kinks and that fix will be coming afterward if I'm able to find a solution.*

### Data Handling From Query

```
if(queryString.Contains("WHERE PM_PRT LIKE"))
{
    //DEBUG: This line of code causes the memory issue, but it was my best attempt
    //at trying to get the data to update as the queries came in. 
    form.partNumberInput.Items.Clear();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //INFO: This is my comboBox and this adds to it for each item
        //returned from the database.
        form.partNumberInput.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

### Expected Solution

> I'd like to be able to poll through my database queries dynamically without overloading the comboBox suggestions that are generated. The suggestions MUST be pulled from the database as items are continually changing minute to minute, and loading at application start isn't an option since it will take quite some time to return that data.

Comment: Have you made any headway?

Comment: @Squirrelintraining not yet I haven’t. Been stuck working on an app. I’ll try your solution sometime tonight.

Comment: Good luck with that :D